# Concat value into API url in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying something very simple in Vue and can't get it to work.. I want my API url to update with 2 new values (valueFrom and valueTwo). I am using fetch for this.

When I console log the values, they work (2021-06-17 etc). But as soon as I put them in the url, it just comes up empty.

Here are my input fields:

```
<label for="dateFrom" class="mr-sm-2">From</label>
          <b-form-datepicker id="dateFrom" v-model="valueFrom" class="mb-2 mr-sm-4 mb-sm-0 w-25" :min="min" :max="max"></b-form-datepicker>

          <label for="dateTo" class="mr-sm-2">To</label>
          <b-form-datepicker id="dateTo" v-model="valueTo" class="mb-2 mr-sm-4 mb-sm-0 w-25" :min="min" :max="max"></b-form-datepicker>
```

Here is the button that calls the fetch:

```
<b-button variant="primary" @click="$fetch()">Search</b-button>
```

Here is my Vue code:

```
    data() {
const now = new Date();
const today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
const minDate = new Date(today);
const maxDate = new Date(today);
maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + 6);
return {
  items: {},
  valueFrom: '',
  valueTo: '',
  min: minDate,
  max: maxDate
}
```

},

```
async fetch() {
  const api = 'https://apiurl.com/ajax/locationSearchJSON/?location=Edinburgh&arrival=${this.valueFrom}&arrivalTime=12%3A00&departure={$this.valueTo}&departureTime=12%3A00
this.items = await fetch(api).then(res => res.json())
```

}

I also tried concating them in the javascript way (' + this.valueFrom + ') but that just rendered an empty string as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the backticks/backquotes (``) in place of the apostrophes. So your url will end up as below:

```
`https://apiurl.com/ajax/locationSearchJSON/?location=Edinburgh&arrival=${this.valueFrom}&arrivalTime=12%3A00&departure=${this.valueTo}&departureTime=12%3A00`
```

Also check the second variable `this.valueTo` has been added to the url correctly. In your case above this is how you've added it:

```
{$this.valueTo}
```

It should be:

```
${this.valueTo}
```